How to check the status of a SendGrid contact deletion job?
In the DELETE /v3/marketing/contacts endpoint sends back a job_id, but unlike other endpoints that process jobs (such as Export Contacts), there's no (documented) endpoint to retrieve the status of a deletion jobs (like Export Contacts Status.
How can I contact the SendGrid API to check what happened with my contact deletion requests?
